# iPhone Passcode Entry Points

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, security, uiapplicationdelegate

I've written a passcode system for my iPhone app, and currently have it working perfectly in the -applicationDidFinishLaunching method, but I was wondering what are the other methods I have to override to account for things like sleep, and multitasking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the app delegate, probably

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

and

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

You might also want to use:

```
- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application;
```

I think that covers it, though.

Comment: awesome, hope this answers the question!